# Bespin and Macbook scroll gestures

Tags: macos, scroll, bespin

I don't know this because I'm on a Sony laptop, but does the Macbook two fingure scrolling work with bespin? The scrolling on my VAIO trackpad doesn't work with bespin. I know this is because the scrollbars are actually canvas drawn and javascript controlled. Sense I want to get a mac eventually, I would like to know if the two fingure scrolling gesture on macbooks and macbook pros work on bespin.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does. up/down and left/right (i.e. if the line is wider than the browser)

It works with the track pad and with the magic mouse.

Comment: Is this because the scrolling on the trackpad on macbooks is the same as scrolling with a mousewheel, as far as the computer can tell?

Comment: in answer to above: i suspect so but not having a wheel mouse cannot confirm. However if you run your finger left to right then it moves the 'frame' left to right (assuming you have lines longer than the frame). To this on a wheel mouse you would need to click the wheel to get the compass like icon, and click again to undo.